# Icon color change on focus-witchin HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

am trying to create container for my input with icon (fontawesome) my div have styles and on focus-witchin does change border. Now I was trying to create it to change color of  same as border color on focus-witchin. It does work when am not setting up color of  (as default black) but when I have set color in css it doesn't work. What's the problem? Please help, thanks!

```css
body {
    background-color: #121212;
}

#form {
    width: 300px;
}

#form .item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #323232;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: all .3s;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#form .item:focus-within {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    color: #fff;
}

#form .item i:active {
    color: #fff;
}

#form input {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0 5px;
    color: #fff;
}

#form input:focus, input:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

#form i {
    width: 10%;
    color: #323232;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7204bf25d6.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <div class="item">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username or email">
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are not changing color for icon check this:**

```css
body {
    background-color: #121212;
}

#form {
    width: 300px;
}

#form .item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #323232;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: all .3s;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#form .item:focus-within {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    color: #fff;
}


#form .item:focus-within i {
color: #fff;
}

#form .item i:active {
    color: #fff;
}

#form input {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0 5px;
    color: #fff;
}

#form input:focus, input:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

#form i {
    width: 10%;
    color: #323232;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7204bf25d6.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <div class="item">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username or email">
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```